# How to display html form next to each other and in rows?

Tags: html, css, forms, display

I am currently trying to get two forms next to each other and then two more forms under it all aligned. If anyone has any suggestions to help me out that would be great. Here is my source code in a jsfiddle.

I am trying to get the name and company input next to each other and then the phone and email below it with the comment textbox at the base. I was trying the 40% width and it sort of helped to get the first row. I was thinking of going the table route as I could probably get that working fine for the forms being aligned but I know tables is not the correct route for coding this.
https://jsfiddle.net/xtwistedmetal/two7hgtm/1/

or

```css
<style type="text/css">
 #mc_embed_signup {
  background: #fff;
  clear: left;
  font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 }
 .mc-field-group1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
 }
 .mc-field-group2 {
  display: inline-block;
 }
 

</style>
```

```html
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
  <form method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate="" action="websitehere">
   <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <div align="center">
     <h2> Wholesale Contact Form</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group1">
     <label for="mce-FNAME">Name </label>
     <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME" />
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group1">
     <label for="mce-MMERGE3">Company Name </label>
     <input type="text" value="" name="MMERGE3" class="required" id="mce-MMERGE3" />
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group2">
     <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address </label>
     <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" />
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="mc-field-group2">
     <label for="mce-MMERGE2">Phone Number </label>
     <input type="text" name="MMERGE2" class="" value="" id="mce-MMERGE2" />
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
     <label for="mce-COMMENTS">Comments </label>
     <!-- <input type="text" value="" name="COMMENTS" class="required" id="mce-COMMENTS" /> -->
     <textarea id="mce-COMMENTS" name="COMMENTS" cols="47" rows="3"> </textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
     <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display: none;"></div>
     <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="clear" align="center">
     <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" />
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try an approach like below

```css
.form-group:after{
  content: "";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
} 
.form-group-half{
  width:44%;
  padding:0 3%;
  float:left;
}
.form-group-half > label{
  display:block;
}
.form-group-half > input,
.form-group-half > select,
.form-group-half > textarea {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-group-half">
    <label>Field 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="field1">
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group-half">
    <label>Field 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="field2">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-group-half">
    <label>Field 3</label>
    <input type="text" name="field3">
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group-half">
    <label>Field 4</label>
    <input type="text" name="field4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML ;

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate="" action="websitehere">
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
            <div align="center">
                <h2> Wholesale Contact Form</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group1" style=>
      <div style="width:40%">
       <label for="mce-FNAME">Name </label>
                 <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME" />
      </div>
      <div style="width:40%">
        <label for="mce-MMERGE3">Company Name </label>
                <input type="text" value="" name="MMERGE3" class="required" id="mce-MMERGE3" />
      </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group2">
              <div style="width:40%">
                <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address </label>
                <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" />
    </div>
     <div style="width:40%">
                <label for="mce-MMERGE2">Phone Number </label>
                <input type="text" name="MMERGE2" class="" value="" id="mce-MMERGE2" />
      </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="mc-field-group">
                <label for="mce-COMMENTS">Comments </label>
                <!-- <input type="text" value="" name="COMMENTS" class="required" id="mce-COMMENTS" /> -->
                <textarea id="mce-COMMENTS" name="COMMENTS" cols="47" rows="3"> </textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display: none;"></div>
                <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display: none;"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="clear" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
#mc_embed_signup {
    background: #fff;
    clear: left;
    font: 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.mc-field-group1 {
    width: 100%;
display: inline-flex;
}
.mc-field-group2 {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
}
label{
   color:red;
   width:40px !important;
}
```